# Can I specify a port for certain IP address in SSH's config?

Tags: ssh

A ssh server on 192.168.1.45 listens on port 2222.  I know I can just add `-p2222` or add an alias in `~/.bash_aliases`, but is there a way to force a certain port when I ssh a specified IP?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Sure, you can put these settings in [`~/.ssh/config`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/ssh_config.5.html).

```
Host 192.168.1.45
Port 2222
```

You can take this opportunity to give the machine a nickname, and set other options, in particular the remote user name. For example, the following declaration makes `ssh foo` equivalent to `ssh -p 2222 matt@192.168.1.45` (`Host foo` means that the following options apply when you run `ssh foo`, and the `HostName` directive makes `foo` a nickname for 192.168.1.45 with all the other options):

```
Host foo
HostName 192.168.1.45
Port 2222
User matt
```

Comment: Tried the bottom [with 'foo'] and it didn't work. ["port 22 refused"].. the other one works though

Comment: @Matt Did you run `ssh foo` and not `ssh 192.168.1.45`? You use the nickname given after `Host`, I should have stated this more clearly in my answer.

Comment: ohh.. no, I guess I misunderstood.

Comment: Is it possible to add custom flags? I'd like to automatically have -q enabled

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX You can't set custom flags, but you can set options. `-q` is equivalent to `LogLevel QUIET`.

Answer (score 3):

You could add the host to your ssh configuration file. Run `man ssh_config` from a terminal for some nice reading.

In short place

```
Host <hostname>
Port 2222
```

in your ~/.ssh/config

Answer (score 0):

For any ec2 instance IP, automatically picks useranme and key file.

`Host *.*.*.* 
     IdentityFile ~/.ssh/key.pem
     Port 22
     CheckHostIP no
     PasswordAuthentication no
     User ec2-user
     UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
     StrictHostKeyChecking no`

Comment: Thank you but does it answer the question (port number)?

Comment: @MarcVanhoomissen thanks for pointing out. I have updated with port